# Use Velocity or FreeMarker for creating e-mail templates

Tags: templates, velocity, freemarker

I would like to generate few templates for sending automated mails from my application.

Can anybody let me know how to generate the templates using velocity or FreeMarker and then include templates in e-mail body as HTML content?

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Freemarker or Velocity to just generate the HTML string, then send a normal email.

Read the documentation, http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html  or http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you stick to FreeMarker for that purpose. Velocity does not natively support HTML-encoding. There's a way to enable this feature as a Velocity extension, but it relies on an environment of a servlet container which is not always available. Fortunatley, FreeMarker's `?html` built-in is a pure Java implementation that works everywhere.