# Reply email format library or method?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm writing an email autoresponder in Java and I want to be able to create a reply format just like when you click reply on Yahoo Mail, Gmail, etc that puts the date, from name, etc on the top of the original message. Is there anything I can use or would I have to code this from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Java template library such as Freemarker/Velocity to compose your email template, and generate the real content by passing data/from name, etc as parameters to the template at runtime.
You can refer to this question:

[Use Velocity or FreeMarker for creating e-mail templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720706/use-velocity-or-freemarker-for-creating-e-mail-templates)